# How to get a disabled div value on C# code behnd?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

On my C# asp.net web application I disabled a div inputs using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[id*=Dis1] :input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Design

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="Dis1">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranch" autocomplete="off" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

When i am tring to take the value from C# code behind as

```
string branch = txtBranch.Text;
```

variable `branch` is getting null value.

is it possible to get this value on code behind or am wasting my time ??
 should i use use jquery to get this value ??

Comment: disabled fields are not post when you submit the data

Comment: @programtreasures so its not possible to get on code behind ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled fields are not submitted while you submit the form, you need to make it readonly instead disable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[id*=Dis1] :input').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

and apply disable CSS to the field,

```
[id*=Dis1] :input {
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

Or else you need to store it in hidden field, and you will able to access the value

Comment: i tried using readonly , but when it comes to dropdown list it wont work ..!!

Comment: @Kirk  store value in hidden field